# FTB direwolf20 1.6.4 crashes when installing ICBM mod

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-direwolf20

I have been playing FTB Direwolf20 1.6.4 for a couple of months while adding mods to it, though it seems that when i added ICBM ftb crashes as it loads in the "MOJANG" screen. Also note that i saw in the crash something wrong with block of concrete, but I don't know how to fix that. Can someone help me with installing it?

This is the crash report

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// Would you like a cupcake?

Time: 13/02/14 11:30
Description: Initializing game

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: icbm/contraption/block/BlockConcrete
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.FMLModContainer.constructMod(FMLModContainer.java:462)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventHandler.handleEvent(EventHandler.java:74)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.SynchronizedEventHandler.handleEvent(SynchronizedEventHandler.java:45)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatch(EventBus.java:313)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatchQueuedEvents(EventBus.java:296)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:267)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.LoadController.sendEventToModContainer(LoadController.java:201)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.LoadController.propogateStateMessage(LoadController.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventHandler.handleEvent(EventHandler.java:74)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.SynchronizedEventHandler.handleEvent(SynchronizedEventHandler.java:45)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatch(EventBus.java:313)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatchQueuedEvents(EventBus.java:296)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:267)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.LoadController.distributeStateMessage(LoadController.java:112)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.Loader.loadMods(Loader.java:511)
    at cpw.mods.fml.client.FMLClientHandler.beginMinecraftLoading(FMLClientHandler.java:183)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_71384_a(Minecraft.java:473)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_99999_d(Minecraft.java:808)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:101)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:131)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:27)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: icbm.contraption.block.BlockConcrete
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.LaunchClassLoader.findClass(LaunchClassLoader.java:186)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: atomicscience/api/IAntiPoisonBlock
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.LaunchClassLoader.findClass(LaunchClassLoader.java:178)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: atomicscience.api.IAntiPoisonBlock
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.LaunchClassLoader.findClass(LaunchClassLoader.java:97)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 40 more


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Head --
Stacktrace:
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.FMLModContainer.constructMod(FMLModContainer.java:462)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventHandler.handleEvent(EventHandler.java:74)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.SynchronizedEventHandler.handleEvent(SynchronizedEventHandler.java:45)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatch(EventBus.java:313)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatchQueuedEvents(EventBus.java:296)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:267)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.LoadController.sendEventToModContainer(LoadController.java:201)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.LoadController.propogateStateMessage(LoadController.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventHandler.handleEvent(EventHandler.java:74)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.SynchronizedEventHandler.handleEvent(SynchronizedEventHandler.java:45)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatch(EventBus.java:313)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatchQueuedEvents(EventBus.java:296)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:267)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.LoadController.distributeStateMessage(LoadController.java:112)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.Loader.loadMods(Loader.java:511)
    at cpw.mods.fml.client.FMLClientHandler.beginMinecraftLoading(FMLClientHandler.java:183)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_71384_a(Minecraft.java:473)

-- Initialization --
Details:
Stacktrace:
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_99999_d(Minecraft.java:808)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:101)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:131)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:27)

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.6.4
    Operating System: Windows 7 (amd64) version 6.1
    Java Version: 1.7.0_01, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 1070320600 bytes (1020 MB) / 1365180416 bytes (1301 MB) up to 3101949952 bytes (2958 MB)
    JVM Flags: 3 total; -Xms256M -Xmx3328M -XX:PermSize=256m
    AABB Pool Size: 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) allocated, 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) used
    Suspicious classes: FML and Forge are installed
    IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0
    FML: MCP v8.11 FML v6.4.49.965 Minecraft Forge 9.11.1.965 Feed The Beast Mod Pack 172 mods loaded, 172 mods active
    mcp{8.09} [Minecraft Coder Pack] (minecraft.jar) Unloaded->Constructed
    FML{6.4.49.965} [Forge Mod Loader] (minecraftforge-9.11.1.965.jar) Unloaded->Constructed
    Forge{9.11.1.965} [Minecraft Forge] (minecraftforge-9.11.1.965.jar) Unloaded->Constructed
    AppliedEnergistics-Core{rv14.finale2} [AppliedEnergistics Core] (minecraft.jar) Unloaded->Constructed
    CodeChickenCore{0.9.0.7} [CodeChicken Core] (minecraft.jar) Unloaded->Constructed
    denLib{3.1.35} [denLib] (minecraft.jar) Unloaded->Constructed
    Evoc{1.0.0} [Evoc] (minecraft.jar) Unloaded->Constructed
    InfiniBows{1.2.0 build 14} [Infinity Bow Fix] (minecraft.jar) Unloaded->Constructed
    Micdoodlecore{} [Micdoodle8 Core] (minecraft.jar) Unloaded->Constructed
    MobiusCore{1.0.4} [MobiusCore] (minecraft.jar) Unloaded->Constructed
    NotEnoughItems{1.6.1.8} [Not Enough Items] (NotEnoughItems 1.6.1.8.jar) Unloaded->Constructed
    PowerCrystalsCore{1.1.8} [PowerCrystals Core] (PowerCrystalsCore-1.1.8-9.jar) Unloaded->Constructed
    switches|pistontweak{1.3.0 build 25} [Switches|PistonTweak] (minecraft.jar) Unloaded->Constructed
    TConstruct-Preloader{0.0.1} [Tinkers Corestruct] (minecraft.jar) Unloaded->Constructed
    Tropicraft-Coremods{v5.1} [Tropicraft Coremods] (minecraft.jar) Unloaded->Constructed
    DamageIndicatorsMod{2.9.2.3} [Damage Indicators] (1.6.4 DamageIndicatorsv2.9.2.3.zip) Unloaded->Constructed
    props{1.4} [DecoCraft] ([1.6.4]DecoCraftV1.4.zip) Unloaded->Constructed
    ccm{1.0.1} [MrCrayfish's Construction Mod] ([Forge]MrCrayfishConstructionModv1.0.5 (1.6.4).zip) Unloaded->Constructed
    advancedgenetics{v1.5 BETA} [Advanced Genetics] (Advanced-Genetics-Mod-1.6.4.jar) Unloaded->Constructed
    arsmagica2{1.1.1c} [Ars Magica 2] (AM2_1.1.1c.zip) Unloaded->Constructed
    AppliedEnergistics{rv14.finale2} [Applied Energistics] (appeng-rv14-finale2-mc16x.jar) Unloaded->Constructed
    Atum{0.5.9B} [Atum] (atum-journey-into-the-sands-mod-1.6.4.jar) Unloaded->Constructed
    BuildCraft|Core{4.2.2} [BuildCraft] (buildcraft-A-1.6.4-4.2.2.jar) Unloaded->Constructed
    BetterFurnaces{3.4} [Better Furnaces] (Better-Furnaces-Mod-1.6.4.zip) Unloaded->Constructed
    BiblioCraft{1.5.3} [BiblioCraft] (BiblioCraft[v1.5.3].zip) Unloaded->Constructed
    Natura{2.1.14} [Natura] (Natura_mc1.6.X_2.1.14.jar) Unloaded->Constructed
    BiomesOPlenty{1.2.1} [Biomes O' Plenty] (BiomesOPlenty-universal-1.6.4-1.2.1.416.jar) Unloaded->Constructed
    BiblioWoodsBoP{1.3} [BiblioWoods Biomes O'Plenty Edition] (BiblioWoods[BiomesOPlenty][v1.3].zip) Unloaded->Constructed
    CoFHCore{2.0.0.2} [CoFH Core] (CoFHCore-2.0.0.2.jar) Unloaded->Constructed
    UniversalElectricity{@MAJOR@.@MINOR@.@REVIS@} [Universal Electricity] (Universal-Electricity-3.0.0.253-core.jar) Unloaded->Constructed
    ForgeMultipart{1.0.0.227} [Forge Multipart] (ForgeMultipart-universal-1.6.4-1.0.0.227.jar) Unloaded->Constructed
    ThermalExpansion{3.0.0.2} [Thermal Expansion] (ThermalExpansion-3.0.0.2.jar) Unloaded->Constructed
    IC2{2.0.316-experimental} [IndustrialCraft 2] (industrialcraft-2_2.0.316-experimental.jar) Unloaded->Constructed
    BuildCraft|Builders{4.2.2} [BC Builders] (buildcraft-A-1.6.4-4.2.2.jar) Unloaded->Constructed
    BuildCraft|Energy{4.2.2} [BC Energy] (buildcraft-A-1.6.4-4.2.2.jar) Unloaded->Constructed
    BuildCraft|Factory{4.2.2} [BC Factory] (buildcraft-A-1.6.4-4.2.2.jar) Unloaded->Constructed
    BuildCraft|Transport{4.2.2} [BC Transport] (buildcraft-A-1.6.4-4.2.2.jar) Unloaded->Constructed
    MineFactoryReloaded{1.6.2R2.7.4} [MineFactory Reloaded] (MineFactoryReloaded-2.7.4-255.jar) Unloaded->Constructed
    MineFactoryReloaded|CompatForestryPre{1.6.2R2.7.4} [MFR Compat: Forestry (part 2)] (MineFactoryReloaded-2.7.4-255.jar) Unloaded->Constructed
    Forestry{2.3.1.0} [Forestry for Minecraft] (Forestry-A-2.3.1.0.jar) Unloaded->Constructed
    BiblioWoodsForestry{1.3} [BiblioWoods Forestry Edition] (BiblioWoods[Forestry][v1.3].zip) Unloaded->Constructed
    BiblioWoodsNatura{1.1} [BiblioWoods Natura Edition] (BiblioWoods[Natura][v1.1].zip) Unloaded->Constructed
    Billund{1.01} [BILLUND] (BILLUND1.01.zip) Unloaded->Constructed
    bspkrsCore{v5.2(1.6.4)} [bspkrsCore] (BspkrsCore-1.6.4.zip) Unloaded->Constructed
    BuildCraft|Silicon{4.2.2} [BC Silicon] (buildcraft-A-1.6.4-4.2.2.jar) Unloaded->Constructed
    Additional-Buildcraft-Objects{1.0.6.182} [Additional Buildcraft Objects] (buildcraft-Z-additional-buildcraft-objects-1.0.6.182.jar) Unloaded->Constructed
    CalclaviaCore{1.0.0} [Calclavia] (Calclavia-Core-v1.0.0.26.jar) Unloaded->Constructed
    ChickenChunks{1.3.3.3} [ChickenChunks] (ChickenChunks 1.3.3.3.jar) Unloaded->Constructed
    CoFHLoot{2.0.0.2} [CoFH Loot] (CoFHCore-2.0.0.2.jar) Unloaded->Constructed
    CoFHMasquerade{2.0.0.2} [CoFH Masquerade] (CoFHCore-2.0.0.2.jar) Unloaded->Constructed
    CoFHSocial{2.0.0.2} [CoFH Social] (CoFHCore-2.0.0.2.jar) Unloaded->Constructed
    CoFHWorld{2.0.0.2} [CoFH World] (CoFHCore-2.0.0.2.jar) Unloaded->Constructed
    CompactSolars{4.4.19.224} [Compact Solar Arrays] (compactsolars-universal-1.6.4-4.4.19.224.zip) Unloaded->Constructed
    ComputerCraft{1.57} [ComputerCraft] (ComputerCraft1.57.zip) Unloaded->Constructed
    CCTurtle{1.57} [ComputerCraft Turtles] (ComputerCraft1.57.zip) Unloaded->Constructed
    ConfigMod{v1.0} [Extended Mod Config] (ConfigMod for MC v1.6.4.zip) Unloaded->Constructed
    CoroAI{v1.0} [CoroAI] (CoroAI for MC v1.6.4.zip) Unloaded->Constructed
    DenPipes-Forestry{1.1.8} [DenPipes-Forestry] (DenPipes-Forestry-1.6.4-1.1.8.jar) Unloaded->Constructed
    DenPipes-Emerald{1.1.6} [DenPipes-Emerald] (DenPipes-Emerald-1.6.4-1.1.6.jar) Unloaded->Constructed
    DenPipes{2.1.18} [DenPipes] (DenPipes-1.6.4-2.1.18.jar) Unloaded->Constructed
    MoCreatures{6.1.0} [DrZhark's Mo'Creatures Mod] (DrZharks MoCreatures Mod v6.1.0.zip) Unloaded->Constructed
    DungeonPack{1.6.4} [DungeonPack] (Dungeon-Pack-Mod-1.6.4.zip) Unloaded->Constructed
    emashercore{1.2.2.0} [Emasher Resource] (EmasherResource-1.2.2.0.zip) Unloaded->Constructed
    EnderStorage{1.4.3.5} [EnderStorage] (EnderStorage 1.4.3.5.jar) Unloaded->Constructed
    eng_toolbox{1.1.6.3} [Engineer's Toolbox] (Engineers-Toolbox-Mod-1.6.4.zip) Unloaded->Constructed
    Explodables{1.8} [Explodables] (Explodables-Mod-1.6.4.zip) Unloaded->Constructed
    ExtendedRenderer{v1.0} [Extended Renderer] (ExtendedRenderer for MC v1.6.4.zip) Unloaded->Constructed
    ExtraUtilities{1.0.1} [Extra Utilities] (extrautils-1.0.2.zip) Unloaded->Constructed
    factorization{0.8.28} [Factorization] (Factorization-0.8.28.jar) Unloaded->Constructed
    factorization.misc{0.8.28} [Factorization Miscellaneous Nonsense] (Factorization-0.8.28.jar) Unloaded->Constructed
    factorization.notify{0.8.28} [Factorization Notification System] (Factorization-0.8.28.jar) Unloaded->Constructed
    factorization.dimensionalSlice{0.8.28} [Factorization Dimensional Slices] (Factorization-0.8.28.jar) Unloaded->Constructed
    flatsigns{1.4.0} [Flat Signs] (flatsigns-1.6.2-universal-1.4.0.15.jar) Unloaded->Constructed
    ICBM{1.4.1} [ICBM] (ICBM-1.4.1.143-core.jar) Unloaded
    ICBM|Sentry{1.4.1} [ICBM|Sentry] (ICBM-1.4.1.143-sentry.jar) Unloaded
    ICBM|Explosion{1.4.1} [ICBM|Explosion] (ICBM-1.4.1.143-explosion.jar) Unloaded
    GalacticraftCore{2.0.8} [Galacticraft Core] (Galacticraft-1.6.4-2.0.8.908.jar) Unloaded
    GalacticraftMars{2.0.8} [Galacticraft Mars] (Galacticraft-Planets-1.6.4-2.0.8.908.jar) Unloaded
    GateCopy{3.1.4} [GateCopy] (GateCopy-1.6.4-3.1.4.jar) Unloaded
    GraveStone{2.4.1} [GraveStone] (Gravestone-Mod-1.6.4.zip) Unloaded
    iChunUtil{2.3.0} [iChunUtil] (iChunUtil2.3.0.zip) Unloaded
    GraviGun{2.0.0} [GraviGun] (GravityGun2.0.0.zip) Unloaded
    Hats{2.1.1} [Hats] (Hats2.1.1.zip) Unloaded
    HatStand{2.0.0} [HatStand] (HatStand2.0.0.zip) Unloaded
    IC2NuclearControl{1.6.2c} [Nuclear Control] (IC2NuclearControl-1.6.2c-ic2-experimental.zip) Unloaded
    inventorytweaks{1.56} [Inventory Tweaks] (InventoryTweaks-MC1.6.2-1.56-b77.jar) Unloaded
    IronChest{5.4.1.649} [Iron Chest] (ironchest-universal-1.6.4-5.4.1.649.zip) Unloaded
    LightBridgesAndDoors{0.1.7} [kris91268's Light Bridges and Doors] (Light-Bridges-and-Doors-Mod-1.6.4.zip) Unloaded
    Thaumcraft{4.0.5b} [Thaumcraft] (Thaumcraft4.0.5b.zip) Unloaded
    LogisticsPipes|Main{0.7.4.dev.96} [Logistics Pipes] (LogisticsPipes-MC1.6.4-0.7.4.dev.96.jar) Unloaded
    lucky{4.2.1} [Lucky Block] (LuckyBlock_v4.2.1_1.6.4.jar) Unloaded
    Railcraft{8.3.2.0} [Railcraft] (Railcraft_1.6.4-8.3.2.0.jar) Unloaded
    madscience{0.81} [Mad Science] (MadScience-MC1.6.4-F9.11.1.965-V0.81.jar) Unloaded
    Waila{1.4.4} [Waila] (Waila_1.4.4b.zip) Unloaded
    TConstruct{1.6.X_1.5.2.1} [Tinkers' Construct] (TConstruct_mc1.6.4_1.5.2.6.jar) Unloaded
    ThaumicTinkerer{2.0} [Thaumic Tinkerer] (ThaumicTinkerer 2.0-44.jar) Unloaded
    MagicBees{2.1.9} [Magic Bees] (magicbees-2.1.9.jar) Unloaded
    Mekanism{5.7.0} [Mekanism] (Mekanism-v5.7.0.12.jar) Unloaded
    MekanismGenerators{5.7.0} [MekanismGenerators] (MekanismGenerators-v5.7.0.12.jar) Unloaded
    MekanismInduction{5.7.0} [MekanismInduction] (MekanismInduction-v5.7.0.12.jar) Unloaded
    MekanismTools{5.7.0} [MekanismTools] (MekanismTools-v5.7.0.12.jar) Unloaded
    MFFS{3.6.0} [Modular Force Field System] (MFFS_v3.6.0.303.jar) Unloaded
    MFR Compat Forestry Trees{1.0} [MFR Compat Forestry Trees] (MineFactoryReloaded-2.7.4-255.jar) Unloaded
    MFR Compat Extra Trees{1.0} [MFR Compat Extra Trees] (MineFactoryReloaded-2.7.4-255.jar) Unloaded
    MineFactoryReloaded|CompatAppliedEnergistics{1.6.2R2.7.4} [MFR Compat: Applied Energistics] (MineFactoryReloaded-2.7.4-255.jar) Unloaded
    MineFactoryReloaded|CompatAtum{1.6.2R2.7.4} [MFR Compat: Atum] (MineFactoryReloaded-2.7.4-255.jar) Unloaded
    MineFactoryReloaded|CompatBackTools{1.6.2R2.7.4} [MFR Compat: BackTools] (MineFactoryReloaded-2.7.4-255.jar) Unloaded
    MineFactoryReloaded|CompatBuildCraft{1.6.2R2.7.4} [MFR Compat: BuildCraft] (MineFactoryReloaded-2.7.4-255.jar) Unloaded
    MineFactoryReloaded|CompatChococraft{1.6.2R2.7.4} [MFR Compat: Chococraft] (MineFactoryReloaded-2.7.4-255.jar) Unloaded
    MineFactoryReloaded|CompatExtraBiomes{1.6.2R2.7.4} [MFR Compat: ExtraBiomes] (MineFactoryReloaded-2.7.4-255.jar) Unloaded
    MineFactoryReloaded|CompatForestry{1.6.2R2.7.4} [MFR Compat: Forestry] (MineFactoryReloaded-2.7.4-255.jar) Unloaded
    MineFactoryReloaded|CompatForgeMicroblock{1.6.2R2.7.4} [MFR Compat: ForgeMicroblock] (MineFactoryReloaded-2.7.4-255.jar) Unloaded
    MineFactoryReloaded|CompatIC2{1.6.2R2.7.4} [MFR Compat: IC2] (MineFactoryReloaded-2.7.4-255.jar) Unloaded
    MineFactoryReloaded|CompatMagicalCrops{1.6.2R2.7.4} [MFR Compat: Magical Crops] (MineFactoryReloaded-2.7.4-255.jar) Unloaded
    Mystcraft{0.10.11.00} [Mystcraft] (mystcraft-uni-1.6.4-0.10.11.00.zip) Unloaded
    MineFactoryReloaded|CompatMystcraft{1.6.2R2.7.4} [MFR Compat: Mystcraft] (MineFactoryReloaded-2.7.4-255.jar) Unloaded
    MineFactoryReloaded|CompatPams{1.6.2R2.7.4} [MFR Compat: Pam's Mods] (MineFactoryReloaded-2.7.4-255.jar) Unloaded
    MineFactoryReloaded|CompatRailcraft{1.6.2R2.7.4} [MFR Compat: Railcraft] (MineFactoryReloaded-2.7.4-255.jar) Unloaded
    MineFactoryReloaded|CompatRP2{1.6.2R2.7.4} [MFR Compat: RP2] (MineFactoryReloaded-2.7.4-255.jar) Unloaded
    MineFactoryReloaded|CompatSufficientBiomes{1.6.2R2.7.4} [MFR Compat: Sufficient Biomes] (MineFactoryReloaded-2.7.4-255.jar) Unloaded
    MineFactoryReloaded|CompatThaumcraft{1.6.2R2.7.4} [MFR Compat: Thaumcraft] (MineFactoryReloaded-2.7.4-255.jar) Unloaded
    MineFactoryReloaded|CompatThermalExpansion{1.6.2R2.7.4} [MFR Compat: Thermal Expansion] (MineFactoryReloaded-2.7.4-255.jar) Unloaded
    TwilightForest{1.20.2} [The Twilight Forest] (twilightforest-1.20.2.jar) Unloaded
    MineFactoryReloaded|CompatTwilightForest{1.6.2R2.7.4} [MFR Compat: TwilightForest] (MineFactoryReloaded-2.7.4-255.jar) Unloaded
    MineFactoryReloaded|CompatVanilla{1.6.2R2.7.4} [MFR Compat: Vanilla] (MineFactoryReloaded-2.7.4-255.jar) Unloaded
    MineFactoryReloaded|CompatXyCraft{1.6.2R2.7.4} [MFR Compat: XyCraft] (MineFactoryReloaded-2.7.4-255.jar) Unloaded
    BuildMod{v1.0} [Build Mod] (ModBuild for MC v1.6.4.zip) Unloaded
    numina{0.1.1-53} [Numina] (Numina-1.6.2-0.1.1-53.jar) Unloaded
    powersuits{0.9.0-84} [MachineMuse's Modular Powersuits] (ModularPowersuits-1.6.2-0.9.0-84.jar) Unloaded
    Morph{0.6.0} [Morph] (Morph-Beta-0.6.0.zip) Unloaded
    NEIAddons{1.9.3.r47} [NEI Addons] (neiaddons-1.6.2-1.9.3.r47.jar) Unloaded
    NEIAddons|AE{1.9.3.r47} [NEI Addons: Applied Energistics] (neiaddons-1.6.2-1.9.3.r47.jar) Unloaded
    NEIAddons|CraftingTables{1.9.3.r47} [NEI Addons: Crafting Tables] (neiaddons-1.6.2-1.9.3.r47.jar) Unloaded
    NEIAddons|ExtraBees{1.9.3.r47} [NEI Addons: Extra Bees] (neiaddons-1.6.2-1.9.3.r47.jar) Unloaded
    NEIAddons|Forestry{1.9.3.r47} [NEI Addons: Forestry] (neiaddons-1.6.2-1.9.3.r47.jar) Unloaded
    NEIAddons|MiscPeripherals{1.9.3.r47} [NEI Addons: Misc Peripherals] (neiaddons-1.6.2-1.9.3.r47.jar) Unloaded
    NEIPlugins{1.1.0.6} [NEI Plugins] (NEIPlugins-1.1.0.6.jar) Unloaded
    notenoughkeys{0.0.3} [Not Enough Keys] (Not-Enough-Keys-Mod-1.6.4.jar) Unloaded
    ObsidiPlates{2.0.0} [Obsidian Pressure Plates] (obsidiplates-1.6.2-universal-2.0.0.15.jar) Unloaded
    OpenPeripheral{0.2.1} [OpenPeripheral] (OpenPeripheral-0.2.1-preview8.jar) Unloaded
    OpenBlocks{1.2.2} [OpenBlocks] (OpenBlocks-1.2.2.jar) Unloaded
    OB{1.0.1 RELEASE} [Orbital Bombardment] (Orbital-Bombardment-Mod-1.6.4.zip) Unloaded
    PluginsforForestry{3.2.30} [PluginsforForestry] (PluginsforForestry-1.6.4-3.2.30.jar) Unloaded
    PortalGun{2.0.2} [PortalGun] (PortalGun2.0.2.zip) Unloaded
    ProjRed|Core{4.2.1.16} [ProjectRed] (ProjectRedBase-1.6.4-4.2.1.16.jar) Unloaded
    ProjRed|Compatibility{1.0} [ProjRed|Compatibility] (ProjectRedCompat-1.6.4-4.2.1.16.jar) Unloaded
    ProjRed|Integration{1.0} [ProjRed|Integration] (ProjectRedIntegration-1.6.4-4.2.1.16.jar) Unloaded
    ProjRed|Transmission{1.0} [ProjRed|Transmission] (ProjectRedIntegration-1.6.4-4.2.1.16.jar) Unloaded
    ProjRed|Illumination{1.0} [ProjRed|Illumination] (ProjectRedLighting-1.6.4-4.2.1.16.jar) Unloaded
    ProjRed|Exploration{1.0} [ProjRed|Exploration] (ProjectRedWorld-1.6.4-4.2.1.16.jar) Unloaded
    QuantumCraft{1.02_mc164} [qCraft] (qCraft1.02_mc164.zip) Unloaded
    row{1.6.4-013.10.21-1} [Rails of War] (Rails-of-War-Mod-1.6.4.zip) Unloaded
    Redstone Arsenal{1.0.0.0} [Redstone Arsenal] (RedstoneArsenal-1.0.0.0.jar) Unloaded
    DrSideburnsSAMod{1.2.2} [Secret Agent Craft] (SecretAgentCraftv1-2-2-1-6-4.zip) Unloaded
    StevesCarts{2.0.0.b1} [Steve's Carts 2] (StevesCarts2.0.0.b3.zip) Unloaded
    switches{1.3.0} [Switches] (switches-1.6.4-universal-coremod-1.3.0.25.jar) Unloaded
    Sync{2.0.0} [Sync] (Sync2.0.0.zip) Unloaded
    TMechworks{12.995565c} [Tinkers' Mechworks] (TMechworks_mc1.6.4_0.1.3.jar) Unloaded
    Translocator{1.1.0.13} [Translocator] (Translocator 1.1.0.13.jar) Unloaded
    TreeCapitator{Forge 1.6.4.r09} [Treecapitator] (Tree-Capitator-Mod-Forge-1.6.4.zip) Unloaded
    tropicraftmod{v5.1 for MC 1.6.4} [Tropicraft] (Tropicraft for MC v 1.6.4.jar) Unloaded
    volleyballmod{v5.1 for MC 1.6.4} [Volleyball] (Tropicraft for MC v 1.6.4.jar) Unloaded
    TwoTility{140101} [TwoTility] (TwoTility-Mod-1.6.4.zip) Unloaded
    UndergroundBiomes{0.4.2a} [Underground Biomes] (Underground-Biomes-Mod-1.6.4.zip) Unloaded
    AIBlock{v1.0} [AIBlock] (Weather v1.59 Mod for MC v1.6.4.zip) Unloaded
    WeatherMod{1.58} [Weather and Tornadoes] (Weather v1.59 Mod for MC v1.6.4.zip) Unloaded
    WR-CBE|Core{1.4.0.6} [WR-CBE Core] (WR-CBE 1.4.0.6.jar) Unloaded
    WR-CBE|Addons{1.4.0.6} [WR-CBE Addons] (WR-CBE 1.4.0.6.jar) Unloaded
    WR-CBE|Logic{1.4.0.6} [WR-CBE Logic] (WR-CBE 1.4.0.6.jar) Unloaded
    mod_ZanMinimap{Not available} [mod_ZanMinimap] (ZansMinimap1.6.4.zip) Unloaded
    McMultipart{1.0.0.227} [Minecraft Multipart Plugin] (ForgeMultipart-universal-1.6.4-1.0.0.227.jar) Unloaded
    ForgeMicroblock{1.0.0.227} [Forge Microblocks] (ForgeMultipart-universal-1.6.4-1.0.0.227.jar) Unloaded
    Launched Version: 1.6.4
    LWJGL: 2.9.0
    OpenGL: GeForce GT 555M/PCI/SSE2 GL version 4.1.0, NVIDIA Corporation
    Is Modded: Definitely; Client brand changed to 'fml,forge'
    Type: Client (map_client.txt)
    Resource Pack: Faithful-1.6.zip
    Current Language: English (US)
    Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
    Vec3 Pool Size: ~~ERROR~~ NullPointerException: null
```

Comment: What does it say in your forgemodloader-client-0.log file? If I remember correctly, that should give you some ID conflicts or something that we can use to help you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because technical support questions about modded Minecraft is off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update caldavia-core, universal electricity, MFFS to the latest versions, and use the latest development version of ICBM: https://bitbucket.org/calclavia/icbm/issue/474/icbm-crash-when-starting-minecraft

However running this combination (with gregtech) on the Direwolf20 pack made all my (MinefactoryReloaded -not true) Factorization stuff disappear. I havent found a solution to this yet.

Comment: Thanks that fixed my problem! Although now I have gregtech and as you said I have a crash and it won't work with gregtech which is annoying since its one of my favorite mods/addons

Comment: If you have the same problem with Factorization (barrels disappearing) it can be resolved by downgrading it to Factorization-0.8.29.jar. I have this combination working now, let me know if you have more trouble, maybe I can help

Answer (score -2):

Try redownloading, it seems it's missing a class for concrete.